# visual studio 2013 std::bind with vector returns empty function

Tags: c++11, msvc12

This code

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct S {
    std::function< void() > func;
    //S( std::function< void() > && f ) : func( f ) {}
};

void foo( const S & s ) {
    if ( s.func ) {
        cout << "ok : ";
        s.func();
    }
    else {
        cout << "fail" << endl;
    }
}

void bar_i( int i ) { cout << i << endl; }
void bar( std::vector< int > i ) { cout << i[ 0 ] << endl; }

int main() {
    foo( S{ std::bind( bar_i, 1 ) } );
    S s_i{ std::bind( bar_i, 2 ) };
    foo( s_i );

    std::vector< int > one = { 42 };
    foo( S{ std::bind( bar, one ) } );
    S s{ std::bind( bar, one ) };
    foo( s );

}
```

http://ideone.com/LIjKCT

compiles fine by MSVC 2013, but when I run the program it prints

```
ok : 1
ok : 2
fail
ok : 42
```

If I give the constructor for `struct S` (uncomment the tenth line) it prints four `ok`.

When I compiled this code (without constructor) by GCC, it printed four `ok`

**Q**: is there a bug in MS's compiler or I'm doing something wrong and I'm just "lucky" with GCC ?

P.S. My studio is "Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013". Version: "12.0.21005.1 REL"

Comment: It prints all ok in my MSVC 2013...

Comment: Thank you, @EdgarRokyan. What is a full version of your studio ? I updated question with my one

Comment: MSVC express 12.0.30723.00 Update 3. P.S. your code looks perfectly valid, at least from my point of view :)

Comment: @EdgarRokyan, I upgraded my studio to Update 5 and got the expected result - all `ok`. Спасибо большое ))

Comment: So looks like a weakness of the particular MSVC compiler version, isn't it?

Comment: @EdgarRokyan, you're right. If you'll answer, I'll vote up for your help

Comment: I think it is unnecessary :)

Comment: Feel free to self answer.  It may help someone searching for this problem in the future.